# (Android) Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.0.0) - attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write documents on Firestore, but getting the following error. I tried with firebase-firestore 24.0.0, 24.4.1 and 24.6.1, but the error persists.

```
2023-06-24 09:02:22.956 24796-24796 ScrollView              com.example.goldallfb                D   onsize change changed 
2023-06-24 09:02:22.957 24796-24796 ScrollView              com.example.goldallfb                D   onsize change changed 
2023-06-24 09:02:22.959 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) fileHasMoved : original inode of /data/user/0/com.example.goldallfb/databases/firestore.%5BDEFAULT%5D.goldallfb2-53ea6.%28default%29 is (77376)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.959 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) Stat of fd(209) : st_mode(100660) st_uid(10346) st_gid(10346) st_ino(77376) st_size(94208)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.960 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) File name of fd(209) : /data/data/com.example.goldallfb/databases/firestore.%5BDEFAULT%5D.goldallfb2-53ea6.%28default%29 (deleted)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.960 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/com.example.goldallfb/databases/firestore.%5BDEFAULT%5D.goldallfb2-53ea6.%28default%29" due to error (2)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.960 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) Stat of /data/user/0/com.example.goldallfb/databases : st_mode(40771) st_uid(10346) st_gid(10346) st_ino(70790)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.960 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) Stat of /data/user/0/com.example.goldallfb : st_mode(40700) st_uid(10346) st_gid(10346) st_ino(76103)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.960 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) Stat of /data/user/0 : st_mode(40751) st_uid(0) st_gid(0) st_ino(838593)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.960 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) Stat of /data/user : st_mode(40751) st_uid(0) st_gid(0) st_ino(838594)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.960 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1) Stat of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(3)
2023-06-24 09:02:22.960 24796-24992 SQLiteLog               com.example.goldallfb                E  (1032) statement aborts at 15: [INSERT INTO mutations (uid, batch_id, mutations) VALUES (?, ?, ?)] attempt to write a readonly database
2023-06-24 09:02:22.985  5482-5546  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{c2d6ae6 u0 com.example.goldallfb/com.example.goldallfb.take_test.InstructionsNew EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5968 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.onAnimationFinished:225 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onAnimationFinished:6193 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onAnimationFinished:2 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.lambda$getFinishedCallback$0:140 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator.$r8$lambda$lRxTVOJy8fX752UbrFno9INW9hE:0 com.android.server.wm.SurfaceAnimator$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run:8 
2023-06-24 09:02:23.007 24796-24796 AndroidRuntime          com.example.goldallfb                D  Shutting down VM
2023-06-24 09:02:23.009 24796-24796 AndroidRuntime          com.example.goldallfb                E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.goldallfb, PID: 24796
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.0.0).
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:539)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.run(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032 SQLITE_READONLY_DBMOVED[1032])
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:330)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:234)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 1032 SQLITE_READONLY_DBMOVED[1032])
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:1222)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:756)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:67)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2629)
                                                                                                        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:2606)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.execute(SQLitePersistence.java:367)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteMutationQueue.addMutationBatch(SQLiteMutationQueue.java:190)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$1$com-google-firebase-firestore-local-LocalStore(LocalStore.java:245)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.get(Unknown Source:8)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction(SQLitePersistence.java:225)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.writeLocally(LocalStore.java:217)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.writeMutations(SyncEngine.java:277)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12$com-google-firebase-firestore-core-FirestoreClient(FirestoreClient.java:227)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:6)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java:441)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.call(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:327)
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
                                                                                                        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:234) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
2023-06-24 09:02:23.013 24796-24796 ample.goldallfb         com.example.goldallfb                W  Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2023-06-24 09:02:23.078 24796-24796 Process                 com.example.goldallfb                I  Sending signal. PID: 24796 SIG: 9
2023-06-24 09:02:23.268  5482-5546  WindowManager           system_server                        E  win=Window{2772af1 u0 com.example.goldallfb/com.example.goldallfb.take_test.InstructionsNew EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true win.mViewVisibility=0 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6529 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6510 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.onExitAnimationDone:5966 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord$$ExternalSyntheticLambda10.accept:2 java.util.ArrayList.forEach:1262 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.onAnimationFinished:8569 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.postApplyAnimation:6243
```

I'm also using SQLite in my android app. I found that the documents are created before SQLite is used (say in activity I) but after using SQLite, following error is thrown in activity I and subsequent activities. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I noticed that when the document path is 'User/test' the document is created but when it it something like 'User/3824729/2023/test/2344', above error is thrown.